# Jquery loop through same elements, get content and rearrange content element by element

Tags: jquery, loops, text, each

I have several html-article-elements. All have the same classes. Inside every article, there is a paragraph with a class called "iwantyou". I want to get the innerHTML/content of this paragraph and place it at the top of the article.

I tried to simply loop. But that gives me the content of ALL iwantyou-divs on the page. So the result is, in every article, I have the text of all iwantyou-divs from the page combined, but I need only the one in the article.

That's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.category-material').each(function(index, value) {
           $('.iwantyou').each(function(index, value) {
             $(".summery").append($(value).text());
            }); 
        });
    
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-weight:bold;
}

div {
  color:blue;
  
}

.summery {
  color:red;
}

p {
  color:grey;
}

span {
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article class="category-material">
  <h1>Numerber One </h1>
    <div class="summery">
      <span>Here the text from iwantyou of first article should go:</span>
    </div>

<p class="iwantyou"> summery no one</p>
<p>not touched</p>
  
</article>
<hr>

<article class="category-material">
<h1> Number Two </h1>
<div class="summery">
  <span>Here text from iwantyou of second article should go:</span>
</div>

<p class="iwantyou">Summery no two</p>
<p> not touched </p>

</article>
```

Comment: You need to use contextual lookups.  All your lookups are global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, use `.find`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category-material').each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).find(".summery").append($(this).find(".iwantyou").text());
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  color: blue;
}

.summery {
  color: red;
}

p {
  color: grey;
}

span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article class="category-material">
  <h1>Numerber One </h1>
  <div class="summery">
    <span>Here the text from iwantyou of first article should go:</span>
  </div>

  <p class="iwantyou"> summery no one</p>
  <p>not touched</p>

</article>
<hr>

<article class="category-material">
  <h1> Number Two </h1>
  <div class="summery">
    <span>Here text from iwantyou of second article should go:</span>
  </div>

  <p class="iwantyou">Summery no two</p>
  <p> not touched </p>

</article>
```

Comment: @Clickmari Well you were using selectors that match the whole document instead of matching only inside the given context

Comment: I think I got it... always tried something with $(this) but did not really know how to use it properly and that you can't do something like $(this).$("element")... what in the end find() does. so again thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the `context` as the second argument to the jQuery selector so they are not global, and are scoped down to the element(s) you are iterating over.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category-material').each(function(index, category) {
    $('.iwantyou', category).each(function(index, iwantyou) {
      $(".summery", category).append($(iwantyou).text());
    });
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  color: blue;
}

.summery {
  color: red;
}

p {
  color: grey;
}

span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article class="category-material">
  <h1>Numerber One </h1>
  <div class="summery">
    <span>Here the text from iwantyou of first article should go:</span>
  </div>

  <p class="iwantyou"> summery no one</p>
  <p>not touched</p>

</article>
<hr>

<article class="category-material">
  <h1> Number Two </h1>
  <div class="summery">
    <span>Here text from iwantyou of second article should go:</span>
  </div>

  <p class="iwantyou">Summery no two</p>
  <p> not touched </p>

</article>
```

Comment: don't really understand what happens but it works. Thank you! this is like iterating throgh the object? pfuh.

Comment: @Clickmari The primary point to absorb here is that when you do `$('anything')`, jQuery performs that selector against the entire document.  So in your case, when you loop over the categories and then try to find the summery elements, if you just do `$('.summery')`, you're going to find all the elements in the document, not just the ones that are children of the category you are iterating over.  *That* is why you have to reduce the scope.